# How to create a JSON array of structs from MySQL using MySQLdb and have control of JSON stylized field names?

Tags: python, mysql, json, mysql-python

I have a semi-complex Python / MySQLdb problem with selecting data from a database and converting that to a specific JSON structure.

I will edit this post with an updated working solution, once working.

First the database table

- table:'**person**'

  - id
  - first_name
  - last_name

Each row represents a person. For the json output, I need an array of structs. Each
element of the array is a struct that represents a row in the table.

**Requirements:**

- I am using Python with MySQLdb to select the data, and so need a solution that works
  with MySQLdb
- The starting and end character would have to be '{' and '}', and not '[' and ']'
- The json stylized fields may be named differently from the DB table field names, so I
  need to have control of that
- The DB table name, may be different than what I want or need for the name of the json
  array, so I need control of that

I want to create an array of structs that would look something like this, where each
row would be an element in the array:

```
{
   "persons": [
    {
       "personId": 1,
       "firstName": "<first_name>",
       "lastName": "<last_name>"
    },
    {
       "personId": 2,
       "firstName": "<first_name>",
       "lastName": "<last_name>"
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in SQL this way (assuming MySQL 5.7.22 or later)

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
    'persons',
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'personId', id,
        'firstName', first_name,
        'lastName', last_name
      )
    )
  ) AS `result`
FROM mytable;
```

Alternatively, you could do a simple query, fetch the results, and build an array of dict objects in Python, then convert the whole array to JSON using `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

When I run this query in query editor, the JSON comes back 100% as expected.

When I run in Pyton (MySQLdb), it returns the JSON between:  ((' ending with ',),)

Is there a way to get rid of that running in Python?  That is removing the first three characters, and the ending five characters shown above.


--- reference from python code:
<class 'tuple'>
(('{"persons": ...}]}',),)

Comment: update:  from the above:  **return result[0][0]** worked to get what I needed in my code.  This worked great - five stars * * * * *.  I have a more complex requirement where this needs another iteration adding another nested collection I will post, really puzzled over that.  And I will be buying your book !

Comment: Thank you for being interested by my book! :-D Be sure to get the Beta of the new revised edition: https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/, and you'll get updates to the digital copy as it is finished.